# Will this regex to find bracketed/parenthesized terms in a string?

Tags: regex, string, powershell, special-characters

Consider:
`"\[|\(phone\)\]"`

We are constructing a metadata field, and need to flag filenames that contain the term "`phone`". Case standards don't exist, so I could see any variation of mixed or single case (`phone` `Phone` `PHONE` etc.) There may or may not be spaces to delineate the words; sometimes there are underscores--so I can't use word boundaries. In **ALL** cases, the word `phone` is included in either brackets `[]` or parentheses `()`.

The regex I'm trying to construct for a Powershell script will look for a pattern of `[` or `(` followed by case-insensitive `photo` and ending with `]` or `)`.

`"\[|\(phone\)\]"`   <-- Is that what I've got here?

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: @nhahtdh - oops...powershell. just edited to clarify that point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd do it by accepting one of two possible solutions,

```
\[phone\]|\(phone\)
```

This way you match either (phone) or [phone], but not [phone) and (photo].

You would have to set a flag to match case insensitive, though. in Javascript for example, you would add an i behind the delimiters, like /[phone]|(phone)/i

Comment: Good thing to note! Thanks. You did mean `phone` instead of `photo`, right? `to` isn't some super specialize wildcard for something, I hope... :)

Answer (score 1):

Powershell uses .NET Regular Expression, so it [has support](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az24scfc.aspx#miscellaneous_constructs) for `(?i)`. But it turns out the Powershell `-match` and `-replace`, and so are `-imatch` and `-ireplace` are [case-insensitive by default](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html). So the regex doesn't have to be too complex:

```
\[phone\]|\(phone\)
```

It will match the text such as: `[phone]` or `(PhONe)`

Note that regex is very specific. In this case, no space is allowed in between the `()` or `[]` and `phone`.

Comment: I was under the impression that regex was already case insensitive, was I misinformed? Also...I know that `?` usually refers to finding the PREVIOUS string zero to one times...what does it mean in the context with the `\i` switch, and at the beginning of the statement `(?:\[phone.....)`?

Comment: @dwwilson66: You are right, they are [case-insensitive by default](http://www.regular-expressions.info/powershell.html). `(?...)` usually indicate special construct (check the document for more info). In this case `(?i)` means enable case-insensitive mode. And `(?:pattern)` means non-capturing group, as opposed to `(pattern)` which is capturing.

Comment: Thanks! More stuff to reasearch! :)